# std::once_flag and std::call_once implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading

I'm implementing `std::once_flag` and `std::call_once` for a particular MinGW build where they are not available, using only stuff available in the rest of the standard. The [required semantics](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) would be easy to implement with something like:

```
struct once_flag {
private:
    std::mutex _M_mutex;
    std::atomic_bool _M_has_run;
public:
    /// Default constructor
    once_flag() : _M_has_run(false) {}

    /// Deleted copy constructor
    once_flag(const once_flag&) = delete;
    /// Deleted assignment operator
    once_flag& operator=(const once_flag&) = delete;

    template<typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
    friend void
    call_once(once_flag& __once, _Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args);
};

/// call_once
template<typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
void
call_once(once_flag& __once, _Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
{
    // Early exit without locking
    if(__once._M_has_run) return;
    unique_lock<mutex> __l(__once._M_mutex);
    // Check again now that we locked the mutex
    if(__once._M_has_run) return;
    __f(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
    __once._M_has_runs = true;
}
```

(notice: I'm aware that stuff starting with `__` and `_[A-Z]` is reserved for the standard library implementation; the point is that this code *is meant to be* the standard library implementation, so it's ok)

However, the `once_flag` constructor is required to be `constexpr` to make sure its initialization is thread-safe (or at least, [so it seems from this mail about `boost::once_flag`](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2013/03/201556.php)); this complicates the matter, since `std::mutex` constructor is *not* `constexpr`. I came up with this kludge:

```
struct once_flag {
private:

    // Use a union to defer the initialization of the mutex to call_once
    union {
        std::mutex _M_mutex;
        char _M_dummy[sizeof(_M_mutex)];
    };
    // Spinlock used for mutex initialization
    std::atomic_flag _M_spinlock = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
    std::atomic_int _M_run_status; // 0: not initialized; 1: mutex initialized; 2: function called
public:
    /// Default constructor
    constexpr once_flag() noexcept : _M_run_status(0), _M_dummy({0}) {}

    /// Deleted copy constructor
    once_flag(const once_flag&) = delete;
    /// Deleted assignment operator
    once_flag& operator=(const once_flag&) = delete;

    ~once_flag() {
        if(_M_run_status!=0) {
            _M_mutex.~mutex();
        }
    }

    template<typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
    friend void
    call_once(once_flag& __once, _Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args);
};

/// call_once
template<typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
void
call_once(once_flag& __once, _Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
{
    // If the function has already run, quit immediately
    if(__once._M_run_status == 2) return;
    // We may not have the mutex yet
    if(__once._M_run_status == 0) {
        // Acquire the spinlock
        while (__once._M_spinlock.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire));
        // Check again; we may be the *second* thread to acquire the spinlock
        if(__once._M_run_status==0) {
            // Initialize the mutex
            new(&__once._M_mutex) std::mutex;
            __once._M_run_status = 1;
        }
        // Release the spinlock (std::mutex constructor is noexcept, so there's no
        // need for fancy RAII)
        __once._M_spinlock.clear(std::memory_order_release);
    }
    // Now that we are sure we have a mutex, acquire it
    unique_lock<mutex> __l(__once._M_mutex);
    // Check again; we may be the *second* thread to acquire the mutex
    if(__once._M_run_status == 2) return;
    // Call __f
    __f(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
    // All done
    __once._M_run_status = 2;
}
```

The basic idea is to use a `union` to defer the actual creation of the `std::mutex` to `call_once`.

The `std::atomic_int _M_run_status` member marks the progress in the process: 0 means that we didn't even construct the mutex, 1 that we have the mutex but the function was not called yet, 2 that we called the function.

The `call_once` has an early exit for the "typical" case (= the function has already run) and uses a crude spinlock to make sure only one thread initializes the mutex. The idea is that the `std::mutex` initialization should be really fast (so a spinlock with no `sleep` should work fine), while the function call may be as long as the client code want, so an `std::mutex` (which should defer to the OS the yielding) is definitely more appropriate.

From a quick glance I think I got the obvious gotchas covered, my main concern is that this *feels* a bit too much complicated, and it somewhat does its job twice - first it has to assure that the mutex initialization occurs only once, then the same has to be done to the function.

The only portable alternative that readily comes to mind is to ditch `std::mutex` and just use a spinlock with a `std::this_thread::yield()` instead. That would remove all the `union`/`std::mutex` initialization kludge, but would add a dependency to the `<thread>` header (which may not be ok if it in turn has to include `<mutex>`).

Comment: Look, one point. According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/mutex the `std::mutex` constructor is `constexpr` since C++11. Why did you say `since std::mutex constructor is not constexpr` ? You can add `constexpr` to the first version of `struct once_flag` and it is compiles. I think you must have said `since std::mutex constructor is not constexpr in MinGW`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I'm not 100% sure how closely you want to follow the standard, but this is missing a (potentially significant) piece: what to do if the selection function throws an exception. From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once):

> If the selected function exits via exception, it is propagated to the caller. Another function is then selected and executed.

Fixing this should simply be a matter of the following:

```
try {
    __f(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
} catch(...) {
    throw; 
}
```

The rest of the mechanisms in your code should then select another function to run, as is required.

As for the concurrency aspect, this should be fine. Since this is for MinGW, which runs on Windows, you can be pretty sure this will be used on an x86/64 processor. Because the x86/64 memory model has release/acquire semantics baked into it, the generated code shouldn't even have any memory fences (e.g. `MOV` is sufficient), so you can be pretty sure about its safety.

(If you happen to be running Itanium or ARM for whatever reason, it should still be fine, however).

You might also want to have a look at [invoke](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke). This would allow someone to use (say) a pointer to member function without having to wrap it in a call to `bind` or a lambda. Boost seems to support this, whether `std::call_once` does as well, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 1. Isn't it already ok? The flag variable is set to 2 only after `__f` is called, so if an exception is thrown the flag remains to 1, the mutex is released (it was locked through a `unique_lock`, which has RAII semantics) and the next thread which was waiting on it is allowed to give `__f` another try.

Comment: 2. Invoke: it may be a nice addition, but it isn't required by the standard, correct? (actually, I'm a bit wary of adding extensions that give meaning to code which wouldn't compile, since in these days of SFINAE they can effectively alter the observable behavior of valid code).

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yes, you're right for point 1, my apologies. For point 2, I'm actually not sure if it is required by the standard or not - although the second answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407553/what-is-the-difference-between-stdcall-once-and-function-level-static-initiali) suggests it might be (the quote from *Section 30.4.4.2 Function call-once*).

Comment: I checked the standard, it seems like it is actually required; thank you for spotting it, I'll go fix it!

Comment: (also, it seems like some DECAY_COPY is involved, I'll have to look up what they mean)

Answer (score 4):

Just a few basic suggestions on code improvement, hopefully someone else will be able to give you a few hints on the concurrency aspects of the code later.

- Please drop the `__` prefixing. I know you wanted to make this look like code from the std library, but the truth is that code in the library headers is obfuscated on purpose. Prefixing everything with two underscores makes the code look soo ugly. There's no reason to do that besides intentional obfuscation, and I'm sure you want your code to be programmer-friendly and maintainable.
- This is begging for an enum:

  > ```
  > std::atomic_int _M_run_status; // 0: not initialized; 1: mutex initialized; 2: function called
  > ```

  Old-style enums convert implicitly to integer, so you can use one of those:

  ```
  enum RunState {
      NotInitialized,
      MutexInitialized,
      FunctionCalled
  };
  ```
- Trim down your comments a little bit. Some are completely pointless, like `// Default constructor`, others are just repeating what can be clearly figured by just reading the code: `// Initialize the mutex`, `// Call __f`...
- I would put all that mutex initialization code inside a separate helper method, since it is fairly complicated and distracts from the whole point of `call_once` which is just running a callback:

  ```
  call_once(once_flag& once, Callable&& func, Args&&... args)
  {
      if (once.m_run_status == FunctionCalled) {
          return;
      }

      // A private member that friend call_once can access
      once.check_mutex_initialized(); 

      std::unique_lock<mutex> lock(once.m_mutex);

      // Check again; we may be the *second* thread to acquire the mutex
      if (once.m_run_status == FunctionCalled) {
          return;
      }

      func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      once.m_run_status = FunctionCalled;
  }
  ```

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking the time to respond, although my actual concern was actually the concurrency aspect and the respondence to the required standard semantic. To address the points you made:

Comment: 1. the point is that this code *is* standard library, as I'm patching the MinGW headers. The code in the standard library isn't "obfuscated" (what kind of obfuscation is adding some underscores before identifiers anyway?). The standard explicitly reserves identifiers starting with `_[A-Z]` at the global scope and identifiers starting with `__[a-z]` in all scopes (or something like that) explicitly for library implementation details, so that anything written by library users before including standard headers shouldn't harm them. So, yes, it's ugly but is pretty much required.

Comment: 2. agreed, I used an `atomic_int` because I'm not sure about the presence/guarantees of `std::atomic<T>` over an `enum`, but it's true that I can use the names just as constants. They'll definitely have to keep the ugly `__` prefix, though.

Comment: 3. The comments above constructors are actually a redundant, they are here because they were in the original gthreads-based implementation of this class from MinGW which I used as a starting base. The mutex intialization comment is here because of the odd placement `new` syntax, although it could be reworded to explicitly address this issue. For the rest, the algorithmic part has been heavily commented on purpose while explaining it to a coworker to address some of his doubts; I think that when dealing with delicate thread-related code it's better to be really explicit.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Well I suspect some of the "ugliness" of the std library code is intentional, even though never stated explicitly, probably in an attempt to discourage people from copying it. Related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180166/why-is-the-code-in-most-stl-implementations-so-convoluted

Comment: 4. I'm not really sure about this; since it's pretty short and there's no individually reusable bit, I prefer to see together all the critical multithreaded part and the state changes of `_M_run_status` instead of jumping around.

Comment: And yep, definitely keep the code explaining the more obscure threading parts, just remove the noisy obvious ones.

Comment: I'm mostly following MinGW/libstdc++ code style, which is open source; the "discourage copying" argument is mostly irrelevant.